# google mock - save EXPECT_CALL then re-use and change clauses

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Let's say you have this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, f1(55)).Times(1);
// use the expectation
// ...

// Now clear it
Mock::VerifyAndClear(&MockClass_obj)
```

Is it possible to
1) Save the expectation
AND
2) Re-use it later and change the clauses?

From [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#the-after-clause) I know it's possible to save `expectations` but there's nowhere else that expounds on what else can be done.

Referring to the above code, I want to do something like:

```
Expecatation exp1 = EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, f1(55)).Times(1);
// use the expectation
// ...

// Now clear it
Mock::VerifyAndClear(&MockClass_obj)

// Somehow modify exp1 to change the cardinality or any of the clauses  
// so that I can make the test immediately readable and convey that it's very much related to the one above":

// Instead of this:
EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, f1(55)).Times(0);

// I wanna do something like
exp1.Times(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible in the way described in question. The Expectation class is just to be used in `After` clause and nothing else - by google-mock design you cannot do anything else with it.

But, with proper encapsulation - you might achieve the goal, like:

```
::testing::Expectation expectF1For55(::testing::Cardinality cardinality)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(MockClass_obj, f1(55)).Times(cardinality);
}
```

And use:

```
auto exp1 = expectF1For55(Exactly(1));
// ...

// ...
expectF1For55(Exactly(0));
```

However I bet, the question is more general than just to cover this very example.

E.g. you can encapsulate entire Expectation - whatever you need - like:

```
class F1Expectation
{
public:
    F1Expectation(MockClass&);
    Expectation expect(int arg, ::testing::Cardinality cardinality = Exaclty(1))
    {
       m_arg = arg;
       return EXPECT_CALL(obj, f1(m_arg)).Times(cardinality);
    }
    Expectation expect(::testing::Cardinality cardinality)
    {
       return EXPECT_CALL(obj, f1(55)).Times(cardinality);
    }
private:
    MockClass& obj;
    Matcher<int> m_arg = _;
};
```

And use:

```
F1Expectation exp1(MockClass_obj);
exp1.expect(1);
// ...

// ...
exp1.expect(0);
```